# Bson cannot be resolved with Mongo DB /Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

I am getting this error on the last line in code below:
The type org.bson.conversions.Bson cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files, I am using Mongo JavaDriver 3.0.2

```
 import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
 import com.mongodb.DB;
 import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
 import com.mongodb.Mongo;
 import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
 import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

public class InsertDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("postsdb");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("posts");

    BasicDBObject doc1 = new BasicDBObject();
    doc1.put("user", "Mike");
    doc1.put("sports", "soccer");
    doc1.put("tweet", "Hi..");

    //String json = JSON.serialize( doc1);
    //BasicDBObject bson = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse( json );

    List<BasicDBObject> docs = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    docs.add(doc1);

    collection.insert(docs);  //ERROR HERE

 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. I've solved it by downloading the [bson jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.0.4/) and adding it to the search path.

The [Mongodb documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/installation-guide/) states the following:

> You can also download the jars [directly](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.0.4/) from sonatype. Note:
>   mongodb-driver requires the following dependencies: [bson](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.0.4/) and
>   [mongodb-driver-core](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.0.4)